# Is there a way to calculate a specific digit of PI

Tags: pi, decimal-expansion

Is there any mathematical I could find a specific digit of

If I had `f(x) = ...` what would the function to return the `x` digit of

e.g.

```
f(1) = 3
f(2) = 1
f(5) = 5
f(12) = 9
```

This is Probably impossible, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: It's apparently possible to directly compute the nth digit of pi in base 16 (and therefore in base 2 as well) using the BBP formula: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Comment: Here is an [OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C1%2C4%2C1%2C5&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: [Possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) in base 16 (and in any base dividing 16).  No known method (other than calculate all the digits up to that point plus enough additional digits to ensure that carries won't change the digit you ask about) in base 10.

Comment: @EricTowers has noted in base $10$ you'd need to calculate prior digits. The standard algorithm for that is due to Rabinowitz & Wagon.

Comment: "Direct" does however not mean "immediately" , calculations have still to be done. But surprisingly , the binary digits can be calculated without calculating the whole expansion. As mentioned, such a formula is not known for base $10$.

Comment: [As of](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.12601) January 29 2022, [there's a decimal option](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Digit-ExtractionAlgorithm.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no function that can do such a thing for base-10 numbers. But if you use Leibniz's formula and change the top part of the sigma (like say, 10) you can calculate a good approximation for pi and look at the last digit.